# Why Android 7 devices show error messages related to native shared libraries

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-7.0-nougat

My Android app is using 3rd party library that uses native libraries.
It is built with targetSdkVersion 21.

When running my app on Android 7 phones (in my example, LG G20), users start getting a visible error message upon process initialization.
The error message screenshot is attached.

[image: Error message shown to the user]

When running the same app on Android 5.x and 6.x, there is no error shown to the user, although there is still a matching warning message in the log. Log message looks like:

*library "/data/app/org.iotivity.base.examples.simpleclient-1/lib/arm/libocstack-jni.so" has invalid DT_NEEDED entry "./obj/local/armeabi/libocprovision.so"
ךibrary "/data/app/org.iotivity.base.examples.simpleclient-1/lib/arm/libocstack-jni.so" has invalid DT_NEEDED entry "./obj/local/armeabi/libocpmapi.so"*

So it looks likes Android 7 "decides" to show to the end user a warning which is kept for the log only in previous versions.

I would appreciate:
1. Ideas on how the error message can be suppressed
2. Hints on what is the right solution for the issue (this is a 3rd party code, but I may try to tweak the build process)

Thanks in advance
Max

Comment: I think it may be related: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/06/improving-stability-with-private-cc.html

Comment: Thanks. Similar behavior, but the error cause seems not be exactly the same.

Comment: Hi, I'm experiencing the same, using Iotivity. Can you check `adb logcat` and make sure it's not like a warning? I'm trying in the emulator, and I don't get the error popup, just linker warnings in logcat. Ultimately the dynamic libraries *are* loaded.

Comment: Hi, I also use IoTivity. Actually, it's a warning that was there for long time. But in Android 5.x and 6.x it had no impact. On the 7.x devices, the warning pops up in front of the end user! (the library is loaded, and the app is funcitonal). The link mentioned by V-master in previous comment - indicates there could be changes in how errors are handled in 7.x .